# How to disable Tab key in Gmail (Chrome or Safari)

Tags: safari, google-chrome, gmail

My grandpa has suffered from a very annoying "problem" in Gmail (on Mac OS under Chrome) for a long time and unfortunately I haven't found a solution for him yet:

When composing in Gmail, each time he types <kbd>a</kbd>, he often accidentally presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the same time (<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> are next to each other), which points the focus to the Send button and when he presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> (for a new line); the email is unintentionally sent.

This happens to him very often (please don't blame my old grandpa, this problem also happened to a lot of people: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/Y9DjPEA_6sk/V7IzWt02iugJ).

I hope that somebody here can help me to find a solution. I would appreciate it a lot! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to use [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) to intercept the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and do nothing with it.

ControllerMate has the ability to have workflows specific to different applications but triggered by the same key presses. (see [Application Specific Programming](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/example/#example_008))

[image]

While most of the examples on the site show how you can do *something* with a key press, you can also choose to turn off the key (disable) or reprogram it to insert 4 spaces (make it a functional tab).

ControllerMate is free for up to 10 "building blocks" so if you are trying to reprogram just your <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it should be completely free for this solution.

Comment: Awesome. I'm going to try and get back soon. Thanks a lot!